# Magento 1.9: Password Reset giving Fatal Error

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, password-recovery

When customer enter email and press button this error comes

> `Fatal error: Class
>   'Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Customer_Forgotpassword'
>   not found in
>   /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Flowpassword.php
>   on line 36`

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:156:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'customer_flowpassword' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `customer_flowpassword`";i:1;s:2832:"#0 /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: check the log file, are you getting this error ?